# Display a cv::Mat (type CV_32F) in a QPixmap

Tags: c++, opencv, qpixmap, qlabel

I am using a camera to get a imgTomo1 image which is a cv::Mat object. It is a CV_32F image.
I am trying to show it on a QLabel using a QPixmap.
Here is my code :

> ```
>    cv::Mat imgTomo;
>    imgTomo1.convertTo(imgTomo,CV_8UC1);
>
>   static QVector<QRgb>  sColorTable;
>
>   // only create our color table the first time
>  if ( sColorTable.isEmpty() )
>
>    sColorTable.resize( 256 );
>
>        for ( int i = 0; i < 256; ++i )
>        {
>            sColorTable[i] = qRgb( i, i, >i );
>        }
>    }
>
>    QImage image( imgTomo.data,
>                  imgTomo.cols, imgTomo.rows,
>                  static_cast<int>(imgTomo.step),
>                  QImage::Format_Indexed8);
>
>    image.setColorTable( sColorTable );
>    _afficheImg->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
> ```

Unfortunately, the image displayed remain black.
I am a bit lost in the format as i'm new to OpenCV. 
I think the conversion should work so i don't really know what i am mising.

EDIT : i have deleted the fllowing line :

> imgTomo1.convertTo(imgTomo,CV_8UC1);

It resulted in a loss of information. 
Now i dont have a black screen anymore but some "snow" (pixel that are witching form 1 to 0 very quicly i guess) and i can't really see what my camera is suposed to show.

Thank you for your answers,
Grégoire

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what's wrong with your code but I used the following code to convert a `cv::Mat` image into a `QImage`.

```
if (frame.channels()== 3){
        cv::cvtColor(frame, RGBframe, CV_BGR2RGB);
        img = QImage((const unsigned char*)(RGBframe.data),
                         RGBframe.cols,RGBframe.rows,QImage::Format_RGB888);
}
else
{
        img = QImage((const unsigned char*)(frame.data),
                         frame.cols,frame.rows,QImage::Format_Indexed8);
}
```

You can even check out the follwing [link](http://codingexodus.blogspot.in/2012/12/working-with-video-using-opencv-and-qt.html) for more information on how to convert `Mat` image to `QImage`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have managed to find out one of the issues. Actually using "the imgTomo1.convertTo(imgTomo,CV_8UC1);" I was converting my float32 to usigned int on 8bit, which resulted in a loss of information. Now, i have an image but it is a bit messed up and there is much "snow" (i dont know how to put it otherwise) on the sceen.

Answer (score 0):

1.Convert CV_8U type

```
       Mat Temp;

       CurrentMat.convertTo(Temp, CV_8U);
```

2.Check the channel number:

```
 int theType = Temp.type();

    int channel_number = (theType / 8) + 1;

    if(channel_number == 4){

        cvtColor(Temp, Temp, CV_BGRA2BGR);
    }
```

3.You can convert Mat type to QImage using this code:

```
        QImage putImage(const Mat& mat)
        {
        // 8-bits unsigned, NO. OF CHANNELS=1
        if (mat.type() == CV_8UC1)
        {

            // Set the color table (used to translate colour indexes to qRgb values)
            QVector<QRgb> colorTable;
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
                colorTable.push_back(qRgb(i, i, i));
            // Copy input Mat
            const uchar *qImageBuffer = (const uchar*)mat.data;
            // Create QImage with same dimensions as input Mat
            QImage img(qImageBuffer, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
            img.setColorTable(colorTable);
            return img;
        }
        // 8-bits unsigned, NO. OF CHANNELS=3
        if (mat.type() == CV_8UC3)
        {
            // Copy input Mat
            const uchar *qImageBuffer = (const uchar*)mat.data;
            // Create QImage with same dimensions as input Mat
            QImage img(qImageBuffer, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
            return img.rgbSwapped();
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "ERROR: Mat could not be converted to QImage.";
            return QImage();
        }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for you for your answer.
As i said, using : 

>CurrentMat.convertTo(Temp, CV_8U);

Was the reason the image I display is totaly black.
I have removed this line and my code ius doing the same things as yours.
My problem is that now, the  image displayed seems full of some sort of "noise" .

Comment: I see your point. The 'snow' dot pixels are most probably stuck pixel. For some reasons, there could be such pixel modifications on cameras. I mean, It comes from the camera. For more information you can look at this  [link](https://photographylife.com/dead-vs-stuck-vs-hot-pixels/)